# Trigger to insert in another database in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, hyperlink, triggers, insert

I am new to Mysql, just trying to understand and learn more. I am trying to write on a table in another database by using a trigger. With the code below i am getting an error which i wonder why. 
practice and practice_2 are my two databases where person and check are the two tables. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `practice`.`person` BEFORE INSERT ON `person` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `practice_2`.check (id,`name`,`surname`) VALUES (NEW.d)
END
```

Comment: Every statement needs a terminator and if you are using begin..end you need to set delimiters, Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Also if you specify 3 columns to be inserted then you have to provide 3 values.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will check the link you have mentioned. Yes i forgot to add all the 3 values.

Comment: so i read about that. Mysql workbench adds that automatically. I managed to come this far but i still get this error.

Comment: CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `practice`.`person_BEFORE_INSERT_1` BEFORE INSERT ON `person` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 
 insert into practice2.chek (id , name, surname) values(NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.surname);

END